# vagrant up fails when destroying and associated drives

Tags: linux, vagrant

When I run `vagrant up` command it give me error while it destroying VM and associated drives.

```
amit@Amit:/var/www/myhomestead/homestead$ vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...


==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...

    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'hashicorp/precise32'


    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/precise32

==> default: Adding box 'hashicorp/precise32' (v1.0.0) for provider: virtualbox

    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise32/versions/1.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> default: Successfully added box 'hashicorp/precise32' (v1.0.0) for 'virtualbox'!

==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise32'...

==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...

==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...

==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead_default_1417506056689_3037

==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...

/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:450:in `initialize': Permission denied - /home/amit/.vagrant.d/data/lock.fpcollision.lock (Errno::EACCES)

from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:450:in `open'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:450:in `block in lock'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:474:in `lock'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:449:in `lock'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:68:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:16:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:32:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'enter code here
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:196:in `action_raw'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:173:in `block in action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:474:in `lock'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Comment: it says already that permission denied!

Comment: yes but why ? i have follow all the steps.

Comment: Maybe your permissions are messed up because you ran it as root and/or `sudo` once; try `chown -R amit:amit ~/.vagrant.d` (assuming those are your user & group names).

Comment: I wonder if you installed something using `sudo`. Try `sudo vagrant up` to see if that fixes it. Not ideal but it will  help you pinpoint it. Also you could try removing `/home/amit/.vagrant.d` and starting again - looks like there's some files in there that are not readable/writable by your normal user (amit?). Note this will destroy your current VMs!

Comment: hi halfer i may be i have tried previously ran with sudo. i think that the problematic reason to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My permission are messed up because of i ran as sudo vagrant up. after that my .vagrant directory owner has changed that's why my vagrant up fails.

thanks Carpetsmoker and halfer for helping me to understand.